# Cannot resolve symbol webView on Android Studio

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to make an application using HTML/CSS/Javascript and i have this running in the MainActivity.java:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView); #The line in question
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
}
```

The problem I'm getting is with the `R.id.webView` in the second to last line. It's saying it cannot resolve symbol for some reason, does anyone know why?

Things I've tried already:

1. Importing

   ```
   import android.webkit.WebView;
   import android.webkit.WebViewClient; (dont need this one but still got it)
   ```
2. Changing capitalization of words in `webView` (`WebView`, `Id` instead of `id` etc)

EDIT: ADDING LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="g24.guidedproject.MainActivity">

    <WebView android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: Well if it can't find R.id.webView then that's where the problem is. Can we see the XML layout where you define the webView?

Comment: Ive added WebView to the component tree in the activity_main. Actually you can see everything that iv done in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJa8xie9WZs  But im stuck here

Comment: Can you just show the part of the XML where you declare your Web View. This video is from May 12.

Comment: https://snag.gy/A0D2tG.jpg

Comment: Damn son i didnt even notice that. I will update my first post.

Comment: @cricket_007 ive updated the first post

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you haven't posted your XML layout I can only just guess, but it has to do most likely that your pre-compiled R.java class does not hold reference to that ID, hence it cannot resolve until you do either one of the following.

1. In scenarios like this, always use `Build -> Rebuild Project` in Android Studio. As last resort, use `File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart`.
2. If the above does not solve it, make sure your [resource id](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) is properly declared:

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></WebView
```

Please note the **+** in-between `@` and `id`. That makes sure the ID is created and put into the `R.java` file. Make sure you re-compile afterwards.

For more info: I suggest you reading the following API Guide from the Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: @UrosTadic Please make sure you add the android:id part to your xml layout. I have forgot to paste the code snippet here the other night. Please see my update.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Don't know about the OP but it helped me. (+1)

Comment: Clean and rebuilt haven't helped me, but Invalidate Caches / Restart helped.

Answer (score 3):

There is no id attribute in your WebView xml tag. Add 
`android:id="@+id/webView"` to it.

This will make it look like:

```
<WebView android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution :

```
WebView view=(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="layoutxml"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:text="https://www.google.com/" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/presence_audio_online" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_sys_download_done" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button18"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/bacrondtexttime"
                android:text="ALL" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button19"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="books" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button21"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="photo" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button17"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="video" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button20"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="More " />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>

   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ref
https://layoutxml.blogspot.com/